# scheduling microsoft teams meeting programatically using c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a question regrading Microsoft teams.

can we programmatically schedule teams meeting using c# code. is this possible ?

leads are appreciated.

Comment: Sharing the detailed answer/code/steps in the answer. Test it out and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Consider upvoting it and accept the answer. So it can be useful to others in the community as well :)

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, you can do it using C#, Graph SDK and [using onlinemeetings API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).
- You can use it using delegated permissions and make sure you have OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite permission set.

Here's the code sample that i tested and it works for me.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
{
    StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-01-12T21:30:34.2444915+00:00"),
    EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-01-02T22:00:34.2464912+00:00"),
    Subject = "Teams meeting"
};

await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(onlineMeeting);
```

- Check the [SDK documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview) for details on how to [add the SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation) to your project and [create an authProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers) instance.

Comment: What does authentic provider contains? . 

Also where are you providing recipient email to create meeting?.

Comment: Hi @BharathKumar, yes Dev is correct and with approach you can check and try this document for [creating a meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-1-create-an-event-in-the-specified-time-zone-and-assign-the-event-an-optional-transactionid-value)by providing attendees.